# Delete table row with JQuery animation in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, datatables

I have an HTML table which uses jQuery DataTables (https://datatables.net/). The rows are rendered with html links to delete a row. I have used the following code to handle the click event of link, delete the row on the server and then animate deletion of the row on the front end.

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete-operation", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var oTable = $('#alloperations').dataTable();
        var operationId = $(this).data('id');

        // Get the parent table row and mark it as having been selected
        // due to the fact rowindex does not work in order in datatables
        var tableRow = $(e.toElement).parents('tr').addClass('row_selected');


        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (answer) {
            if (answer) {                
                // send request to delete operation with given id.
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'delete',
                    url: "/operations/" + operationId,
                    success: function () {                       
                        var anSelected = fnGetSelected(oTable);

                       //Get all the row cells and animate a deletion
                        tableRow.children().animate({ backgroundColor: "red", color: "black" }, 300, function() {
                            tableRow.fadeOut(2000, function() {
                                oTable.fnDeleteRow(anSelected[0]);
                            });
                        });

                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        $("#messageContainer").html(result.responseJSON.ResponseView);                       
                    }

                });
                return true;
            }
            else {
                // User clicked cancel
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
```

**QUESTION**: This works perfectly in Chrome but does not work at all in Firefox, does anyone know how I would get it to work in Firefox as well?

Comment: Any error in FF console?

Comment: I think e.toElement returns undefined under FF. Can you check it on your side?

Comment: Try that instead: `var tableRow = $(e.target).parents('tr').addClass('row_selected');`

Comment: Thanks A. Wolff that solved it perfectly. Do you want to add it as a response rather than a comment and I can credit it to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the cross browser property 'target' of event object:

```
var tableRow = $(e.target).parents('tr').addClass('row_selected');
```